# Reset view state or hidden fields before redirecting to avoid resubmit current page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net-2010

I have aspx page that has some hidden fields once the page is submitted i  delete/reset the hidden values the page has hyperlink that redirects page within javascript `"window.location.href = strURL;"` . The problem is if the user cancels the redirected page then while loading the current page it goes throw  `Public Overrides Sub DoSubmit()` function and since the hidden fields are populated via view state it tries to save values again. How to do i reset hidden values/view state to avoid before redirecting?